# MySQL InnoDB tables are missing and not counted in database structure

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a serious problem in my MySQL tables , once there were InnoDB tables which were IN USE and now are somehow hidden

look at this [pic] **Link removed* - the number of tables in heading is 79 and actual counted number is 74.

these tables are those that were IN USE

I don't have any recent backup of my database , so this would game of life and death for me

I checked my VPS, I found them at /etc/lib/mysql/db_name/.

**EDIT :**

I Searched around internet and I found out that every table should have 3 files related to it.

For example, the table `table_users` has:

```
 -- table_users.frm
 -- table_users.MYD
 -- table_users.MYI
```

and for those hidden table , there are only .frm files and the other two files of a table are missing.

**I should change my question to: How to recover a innodb table from a .frm file?**

Comment: Can you manually run "SHOW TABLES" and check if your tables are there?

Comment: yes I did that and it listed all tables including those that are missing

Comment: what happens when you try to query the missing tables.,.

Comment: @ovais yes they are listed there and when i run this sql query : select * from table_users it returns table_users doesn't exist . I'm really tired of this

Comment: A .frm file contains only the field defitions for a table. It will not have any of the table data. As such, you cannot recover anything other than the table's structure if all you have is a .frm file.

Answer (score 6):

InnoDB does not have those three files

InnoDB data is stored in "ibdata1" for all databases and tables.
the table definition is stored in "tablename.frm"

I would say that your InnoDB file has become corrupted, you may want to have a look at these tools:
https://launchpad.net/percona-innodb-recovery-tool

Comment: this is very techinical , I don't know how to install the recovery tool although , I have read all the documentation . this page is my exact problem : http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/12/17/recovering-create-table-statement-from-frm-file/comment-page-1/#comment-809748  and he gave a solution for it , but when I'm with the instruction it returns Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Comment: Yes, this is because your ibdata1 file has become corrupted and MySQL is crashing trying to read it. I would look at employing Percona's services to recover the table (http://www.percona.com/mysql-consulting/data-recovery/)

Answer (score 1):

*UPDATED*

First of all, about the files:

- .frm - table structure;
- .myd - table data;
- .myi - indexes.

To recover tables, you can try (make backup first):

1) run `check table tablename` - for all db tables;
2) run `repair table tablename` - for necessary tables.

---

*UPDATED ONCE AGAIN*

Another idea... Try this:

1. Create a new database to restore and create the tables with same name as .frm files (with the one field - only to create new .frm files);
2. Stop mysql service and replace the created .frm files with yours;
3. Start mysql service and check.

I expect correct tables (without data, of course). And sorry, for now I have no PC to check, before suggesting...

Comment: this is for hiding a table while my tables are hidden , I updated my topic please read it again .

Comment: good and i knew it , but this is what i get as a result of running check and repair commands :   Can't find file: './database/table_users.frm' (errno: 13

Comment: And is the path to `table_users` correct (<curr_location>/database/table_users.frm)? Maybe, permission problems there?

Comment: when I change owner and group of table_users.frm to mysql and refresh phpmyadmin its gone and if I enter Check Table ... it says There is no such a table and then when i chown and chgrp back all files into root (username) its there and IN USE

Comment: @kpower., the guys missing tables are innodb and they don't have .myd/.myi files., neither can they be repaired like this,.

Comment: @ovais : nice one , yep i thought so , Please tell me there is a way to fix these tables and recover the data

Comment: @mac,. yes possible., do you see the tables when you execute "SHOW TABLE STATUS",. if yes,. what happens when you try to query the hidden tables??

Comment: @ovais yes they are listed there and when i run this sql query : select * from table_users  it returns  table_users doesn't exist . I'm really tired of this , I almost tried every trick

Answer (score 1):

actually me too was having the same problem with the missing two files. later i found that when the table's type is innodb then the database folder would have only one associated file.

but you can change the table type to myisam to get all three file for the table.

now as per the backup, you can export the database whenever and wherever you want :)

PHP is GREAT :)

Answer (score 1):

![innodb image][1]                      INNODB SYSTEM TABLESPACE

> INNODB system tablespace is contain in the mysql data directory---

INNODB is system tablespace is divde into ***two parts***

1>.frm
      it can describe the table format or you can say it is a **table **definition****

2>.ibd
       it is contain all system related file and it is also contain data and index       and     ( InnoDB main table space contain – ibdata1 – and redo logs – ib_logfile*.)
ibdata1 contains your InnoDB database and ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1 are log files for InnoDB.

If you delete your ibdata1 file, then all your InnoDB tables will be lost.

***By default, InnDB uses a shared "tablespace," which is one or more files from a single logical storage area. All InnoDB tables are stored together within the tabespace (from all the databases). By default, InnoDB creates two 5MB log files in the data directory: iblogfile0 and iblogfile1. The information is logged in circular fashion, with old information at the front of the log being overwritten when the log fills up.. Consequently, a larger log allows InnoDB to run longer without having to force changes recorded in the logs to be applied to the tablespace on disk.***